# Got some problem on trying to make new GUI wallet translation

Tags: language

I'd like to translate the GUI wallet for traditional Chinese

That might be the only thing I can contribute for now

But I never did this kind of work before, so did a little search on that

Then I download the en.ts file from github

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/tree/master/translations

When I open it with my Qt linguist, it showed unexpected tag error

I don't understand what happened.

Seems some symbol needs to escape in that file, but how?

Comment: Make sure the flie you downloaded is not corrupted. The download might have terminated unexpectedly. If it is really OK, then please quote the exact error mesage, it will help those who know that tool make better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem.

I compared the file content I downloaded and the file on github

there are extra sections start like this

html lang="en" class=" is-copy-enabled is-u2f-enabled"


Then I changed the way download file:

Right-click save as from raw page instead on the github file list

And it just works! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem.

I compared the file content I downloaded and the file on github

there are extra sections start like this

html lang="en" class=" is-copy-enabled is-u2f-enabled"

Then I changed the way download file:

Right-click save as from raw page instead on the github file list

And it just works! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with Qt linguist (Qt 5.7, installed with official installer) on Windows, file opened without any errors.

Comment: Thinks, I solve the problem and indeed Qt5.7 works well.

I posted my solution. Thanks!